# Figure is oversized horizontally in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I insert a figure into `tcbitemize` environment of `tcolorbox`.
The figure width is set to \textwidth. So the figure should be fully in box.
In fact however, I get a horizontally oversized figure, that is to say, the right side of the figure is out of the box.
Why and how to solve it?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

    \begin{document}

    \tcbset{clearsep/.style={%
        boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt}%
    }

    \begin{tcolorbox}[clearsep,colframe=orange,boxrule=2pt,sharp corners]
      \begin{tcbitemize}[clearsep,boxrule=2pt,colframe=green,sharp corners,raster columns=1]
         \tcbitem \includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{logo_st}
      \end{tcbitemize}
    \end{tcolorbox}

    \end{document}[!
```

[image: another original figure]
[image: another example clip]
[image: example figure]

[image: original figure]

Comment: The problem **is not** the LaTeX code but your image. Check where are the borders of the image with  `\fboxsep0pt\fbox{\includegraphics{NqH4C.png}}`. There are not any right white space in your logo. Repair  the image in GImp or similar. Anyway your image will be pixelated. Consider make the logo in SVG format with Inkscape  and then convert it to pdf.

Comment: BTW,  I think that `width=.92\linewidth` is (more or less) what you want, without fix the image.

Comment: @Fran I want my figure fully fill the box horizontally, so width=0.92\linewidth is not what I want. I tried 1.0\linewidth, the result is the same as 1.0\textwidth. I tried with other figures, and get the same result.  And I tried \fboxsep0pt\fbox{\includegraphics{NqH4C.png}}, but don't know how to check the border.

Comment: just open the second image that you posted  in a new tab and see: The logo in your image is not well centered. So you have two options: (1) edit the image with a paint program to center the logo , or (2) reduce a little the with of the imagen in the LaTeX code,  so it leave unfilled some space at the right side as  big as the the white space of the logo at the left side.

Comment: A hi-res (and centered) version of the Skyteam logo is available at https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Skyteam_Logo_Alliance.png

Comment: Ok, I'll try it, @user94293

Comment: The image appears to be out of the box, but it isn't. Try the following in your example: \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2pt]{logo_st}, then \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-1pt]{logo_st}, then \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-0.5pt]{logo_st}. Reduce the subtracted length to 0.1pt. This may convince you, or it may not.

Comment: Though this is not what I want, but thank you @corporal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logp source image￼ is too cropped on the right (even is lost a  bit of the semicircular shape). Also the space at top and bottom is less that in the left side.

Some solutions to correct this are:

1. Fix the source image with a paint program as Gimp.
2. Reduce a bit the width of impressión the image, to `.92\textwidth` for instance,  so at least the logo will appear centered in the box, but that will leave more space in the sides that in top and bottom.

   3. Use the `trim` option of `\includegraphics` to correct the spaces at both sides (change the 6 and -5 values of the MWE as needed):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\tcbset{clearsep/.style={boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt}}
\begin{tcolorbox}[clearsep,colframe=orange,boxrule=2pt,sharp corners]
\begin{tcbitemize}[clearsep,boxrule=2pt,colframe=green,sharp
 corners,raster columns=1]
\tcbitem \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,trim=6 0 -5 0]{NqH4C.png} 
% Note: NqH4C.png is the second image from the question *as is*, 
% but *without any space* in the filename. Just download it 
% without renaming will not work !!
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Anyway, it is always a bad idea to enlarge too much an PNG or JPG image. Any image of bitmap type should have a final resolution of at least 300 dpi (dot per inch) to be printed with a decent quality. Your image have only 148 pixels, so it should not be printed ideally with a width of much more than 1.25 cm to look smoor to the human eye.

Instead, vectorial images, as SVG converted to PDF, or a `tikz` figure could be enlarged as you want without any loss of apparent quality.

Edit:

The OP is still convinced that the problem are not only the images and add a mushrooms image to demostrate the problem, but just changing the logo by this image in the MWE of the question, the image fit perfectly in the green frame, even zoomed at 1600% in a `xpdf` viewer. The following capture of the bottom right corner is made only with a zoom of  400% to allow to check that it was made with the mushrooms image:

[image: mwe]

Therefore, maybe the OP have a problem of an outdated TeX installation, or a PDF viewer with a bad zoom, but  anyway  seems a  "too localized" problem to provide any solution.

Comment: Many thanks @Fran, both method 2 and 3 need to try different values of argument many times to get an appropriate result. That's not convinient. The argument \linewidth which is used in a tocolorbox gives the size of the figure. But for some reason, in my example the width of figure is wrong(a little bigger). I don't think it is a cause of figure itself because I have tried some other figures which give the same effect. So, I guess the root reason is that the \linewidth(or \textwidth) is wrongly calculated. But what causes this? Is it a bug of tcolorbox?

Comment: @lyl Not at all. At least with an updated TeX Live 2018 there are not any bug of  tcolorbox at this respect. Just change your image by `example-image` without extension or with extension .png, .jpg and .pdf (or many others listed  in the manual of the `mwe` package) in your MWE and you must see the whole images **perfectly fitted** in the tcolorbox  frames in all cases. Otherwise it could be that you have an outdated distribution, but again, as far I can see you have only a bad image, not a buggy code.

Comment: I followed your suggestion -- change to anothor figure which is downloaded from the GIMP website. Would you have a look at the figure which is clipped from the low right corner, it showes that the width of the figure is still oversized. Why?

Comment: @lyl I cannot reproduce this last problem.  In my computer the mushrooms image also fit perfectly, so I am afraid that I cannot help further.

Comment: @ Fran Many many thanks for your help and patience!